# Linux to Windows cross-compilation, multiple libraries

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mingw, cross-compiling

I have a finished program that I would like to distribute to a colleague, and can find no "de-facto" tool chain or resource or guide, or even an opinion, on the best approach to cross-compilation. I know that there is rarely ever a cookie cutter solution, but I am still surprised by the lack of information in this regard.

I have begun trying to cross-compile all of the libraries that I use (and their dependencies) but of course, it is not going smoothly. For reference I decided to go with the basic instructions [here](http://www.swarminglogic.com/article/2014_11_crosscompile2). I have followed the instructions exactly as you see them.

Conveniently enough, I needed the png/jpeg/zlib libraries that are used as examples in the link above. I was also able to successfully cross-compile libtiff and leptonica. With that momentum, I then moved on to one of the more beastly libraries -- Tesseract. At this point, during the `./configure ....` step, it says that it cannot find leptonica. I don't understand, as the pertinent leptonica files are installed, right where I (and the link above) want them to be. The rub could be rooted in the way that tesseract is built, it differs slightly from the prior libraries I built previously. Tesseract goes `autogen.sh -> configure -> make ->make install`. I have no idea how to mitigate this.

So my question: Should I continue to bother down this route? The other libraries that I use are openCV, and ImageMagick. If I should, can someone please ease my pain. If I should NOT continue down this route, what is the easiest way to switch to my (very old) windows XP computer, and package up this software? I doubt some of the software I use would even support development on that platform.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe you can install Oracle's VirtualBox for free (it works really well) and install a Windows XP inside it - then you have a nice, easy-to-use, reliable modern machine with XP running on it without getting out extra cables, keyboards and monitors.

Comment: Are there free, legal .ISOs out there? This is probably the best solution.